# Fixed height and width on td cells--HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to put a fixed height and width on my cells:

The tables get bigger if there is a long array on $elem

```
 <table align="center" class="data_table vert_scroll_table" >
              <tr>

                  <c:forEach var="heading" items="${results.headings}"> 

                      <th class="narrow">${heading}</th>

                  </c:forEach>
              </tr>
              <c:forEach var="row" items="${results.data}">
                  <tr>
                      <c:forEach var="cell" items="${row}" varStatus="rowStatus">
                          <td class="narrow" style="width:75px;height:75;">
                              <c:choose>
                                  <c:when test="${results.types[rowStatus.index].array}">
                                      <c:forEach var="elem" items="${cell}" varStatus="cellStatus">
                                      <span class="mouseover_text" title="${elem},&nbsp;">${elem}<c:if test="${!cellStatus.last}">,&nbsp;</c:if></span>

                                      </c:forEach>
                                  </c:when>
                                  <c:otherwise>
                                          ${cell}
                                  </c:otherwise>
                              </c:choose>
                          </td>
                      </c:forEach>
                  </tr>
              </c:forEach>
              </table>
```

css:

```
   table.data_table
{
    border: 2px gray solid;
}
table.data_table td,
table.data_table th,
table.data_table th.header2
{
    font-size: 7.5pt;
    white-space: normal;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
```

Comment: So just define a fixed height + width by applying the corresponding CSS attributes. In other words - what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.data_table {table-layout: fixed; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "table-layout:fixed" as part of the CSS of the table. Maybe this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have problem with you height because you don't define it correctly:

```
<td class="narrow" style="width:75px;height:75;">
```

put the px like that :

```
<td class="narrow" style="width:75px;height:75px;">
```